# Escape backslashes in Swift string literals

Tags: swift, string, escaping

I have strings like this where the `\/` is supposed to be part of the string value.

```
["medium-video\/mp4",
"hd720-video\/mp4",
"medium-video\/webm",
"small-video\/3gpp"]
```

Swift complains about the backslashes. I tried `\\/`, but then the strings have `\\/` rather than `\/` when trying to use them. Not sure how to fix this.

If I print the array using double backslashes, they just appear in the string rather than the `\/` I'm expecting.

```
["medium-video\\/mp4", "hd720-video\\/mp4", "medium-video\\/webm", "small-video\\/3gpp"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming *the "/" I'm expecting*.)
**Seems bad assumption. Just kept here as history...**

Just replace `\/` with `/`.

Each language defines its valid escape sequences, in Swift (or in standard-C) `\/` is not a valid escape sequence and slash cannot be escaped.

(In JSON, `\/` is valid but you have no need to escape slashes.)

Anyway, in Swift:

```
["medium-video/mp4",
"hd720-video/mp4",
"medium-video/webm",
"small-video/3gpp"]
```

---

**Assuming *the `\/` I'm expecting*.** You already have the right answer.

```
["medium-video\\/mp4",
 "hd720-video\\/mp4",
 "medium-video\\/webm",
 "small-video\\/3gpp"]
```

One thing you are mistaking, I guess, is how you confirm the content of Array of Strings.

```
let arr = ["medium-video\\/mp4",
 "hd720-video\\/mp4",
 "medium-video\\/webm",
 "small-video\\/3gpp"]

print(arr)
```

> ```
> ["medium-video\\/mp4", "hd720-video\\/mp4", "medium-video\\/webm", "small-video\\/3gpp"]
> ```

The above may not be a good way, as Swift uses debug notation to print out the content of Array. To check the actual content in an Array of Strings, try this.

```
arr.forEach {print($0)}
```

> ```
> medium-video\/mp4
> hd720-video\/mp4
> medium-video\/webm
> small-video\/3gpp
> ```

Comment: I had to update the text of the question. SO was escaping my example strings. =/

Comment: @Geuis, Maybe you are confused with text representation of a String and its actual content. When you write `"medium-video/mp4"` in Swift, its actual content is `m` `e` `d` `i` `u` `m` `-` `v` `i` `d` `e` `o` `/` `m` `p` `4`. When a text representation of JSON string given as  `"medium-video\/mp4"`, its actual content is  `m` `e` `d` `i` `u` `m` `-` `v` `i` `d` `e` `o` `/` `m` `p` `4`. If you want a String with actual content `m` `e` `d` `i` `u` `m` `-` `v` `i` `d` `e` `o` \   `/` `m` `p` `4`, you have solution in your edited question. Please explain what you really want to get.

Comment: I think there is some confusion based on mis-formatting of my original question, which I went back to correct. Ok, I'm getting data in a json response from an api which is literally `medium-video\/mp4`, backslash included. In Swift, I'm writing an array of matching strings that need to match the json strings exactly, i.e. need to match with `\/` in them. But when I try to write those variables in Swift, the backslash is required to be escaped, but then when I do the extra `"\\"` shows up in the value, i.e. `medium-video\\/mp4` instead of `medium-video\/mp4`

Comment: Ok, I have found it when I was editing my comment above. Seems  you are confused with text representation of a String and its actual content. In many cases, Swift outputs String-literal like text representation, not its actual content.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I understand now, what print() was showing was not what the values actually are. Thanks!